# Como validar que una fecha no sea la misma que otra ya registrada

Tags: php, sql

Hola buenas noches estoy haciendo un sistema de control de citas medicas para la universidad y ya logre hacer el crud completo a la bdd y me registrar todo sin problemas pero no logro validar que cuando el usuario escoja la misma fecha no ingrese ese dato a la base de datoss??

He estado intentando y no logro solucionar ese problema .

El sistema esta hecho en PHP y Mysql.

Saludos Cordiales!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Como la pregunta no contiene suficiente información acerca del diseño de datos debo ofrecerte unas seudo solución:

1. El método que actualiza las citas debe incluir una consulta de preexistencia de cita similar a: `SELECT * FROM tabla_de_citas WHERE iddeusuario = uid AND fecha = lafecha;` donde `uid` es el id del usuario y `lafecha` es el dato a registrar para aquel.
2. Si la consulta contiene registros, hay cita registrada y se debe reportar sin hacer registro.
3. En otro caso actualizas.

Tambien puedes usar la clausula `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, pero puede resultar en actualización silenciosa del registro sin notificar al usuario que ya tenía un registro anterior. Consulta la documentación oficial de MySQL: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)